# Is it possible IE8 will render CSS differently in Windows 7 vs Windows XP

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Totally confused.
At work, I have an older Windows XP machine (I have no choice) and on it I have IE8.
My boss has a laptop with Windows 7 and IE8.

I have a working prototype website with an IELegacy CSS that does some tricks to the CSS to make some things work in my Windows XP IE8.  These tricks are small, mostly spacing issues. (Yes, I know, I don't like still resorting to doing this, but sometimes you have no choice.)

However, all the things in the ielegacy.css plus some other spacing issues go all wrong and totally wonky on my boss' Windows 7 IE8 machine. (like data blowing out of its containing cell in a table! how is that even possible - its a table).

I have no idea how to fix this.

So I ask the collective... is it even possible that IE8 can be doing different things on different versions of Windows?  or is something else going on here?

If so, any ideas on how to adjust for that?

Also, if so, just kill me now :)

Thanks
JD

PS - I have no comparison screen grabs.. I will try to get some.

Update - thanks all - Compatibility View was the culprit. I totally forgot about it.  (I only use IE for testing).  Everybody had excellent troubleshooting ideas, and I agree, I did not provide enough info.  (FYI fonts are standard MS Arial because I need full UTF-8 and I don't need pixel perfect...).  I appreciate it!
Now I just need to get Compatibility View and non-Compatibility View to match up - which shouldn't be too hard. I just needed to understand what was going on. Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't sound particularly likely that IE8 is behaving differently on Win XP vs Win 7. `"some other spacing issues go all wrong and totally wonky"` - you need to expand on this, those screenshots will help. There's probably some other issue at work.

Comment: Maybe he has his browser set to compatability mode or something and it is rendering as IE7.

Comment: If you're layout needs to be pixel perfect, the font rendering of each platform may be an issue.

Comment: totally agree with @thirtydot that you are giving so little info, related to your CSS and font used/available.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked to see if one of the browsers are in compatibility mode while the other isn't?

If you used the internet explorer developer toolbar (I believe the shortcut is F12) you can also change the engine your IE is using to render the site, making it render differently.

Comment: Good call, I think Compatibility view is the culprit.  Forgot all about it. So how do I fix this? .. with Compatibility view ON... my legacy style sheet 'kinda' work... set up the legacy style sheet only work on IE 7 or earlier?  Is that what Compatibility mode is simulating?  Thanks again..

Answer (score 3):

After reading the rest of the comments/answers:

You fix it by:

- Making your site work in IE7, because that's what Compatibility Mode is "simulating". Your site should ideally work in Internet Explorer 7, as it's still used by a smallish percentage of users.
- Figuring out why your site is arbitrarily sometimes in IE7 mode. Your site should be in IE8 mode *all the time* in IE8.
- It's rather complicated, see: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes
- **A simple fix would be to add this meta tag:**

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  ```

  This should (almost) always force the most up-to-date IE browser mode, and [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) if it's available.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.  To clarify - the site does work in IE7 and 6, and I agree it has to work - from server logs I know a good portion of my users actually do use 7 and 6, so I always test for them.  The issue I'm having is with a jQ plugin for table managment and then only a few small things - placement of some positioned/floated graphics that aren't working (same old, same old when dealing with the IEs).  So 99% of the site is fine.  Its just the little things I'm trying to get lined up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

All other things being equal, IE8 should render the same on XP and Windows 7.  It's more likely that accessibility settings, caching, missing fonts, screen resolution, and/or plugins are causing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

after readindg your answer of user681919:

Do you have something like this in your code?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

This force to render a page in IE7

or it could be that your browser is in quirk mode (when you have errors in the HTML and it cannot render properly it switch to a "safe mode" rendering)
Here some more details:http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html