# Same HTML gives Different Layout on Different Hosts

Tags: html, css

This code (which is a working snippet from actual pages) works as expected on Safari & Firefox and, on one virtual host on IE7 & 8 as well, but when it is moved to another host the 'fixed' position is ignored on IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .alrtfrnt   { background-color:gray;}
        .alrtfrnt   { position:fixed;top:33%;left:33%;height:150px;width:300px;z-index:9;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='alrtfrnt'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the 'fixed' is changed to 'absolute' then it is works fine, but that is not the requirement.

It is not likely to be a cacheing issue because this started out with 'real' pages and has continued through some entirely new pages. I have also changed the colour on the block to make sure that is being picked up and set IE to check for updates on every page visit.

I am at a loss as to why exactly the same code should display in a different fashion depending on the server, so any clues as to the next thing I can check or change would be appreciated.

Comment: It is nonsensical that a page that was exactly the same in terms of HTML/CSS/script textual output would display different for different server environments (your host). Please provide some links to demonstrate.

Comment: One explanation might be caching, since that is based on the domain name. Make sure you clear you cache before reloading the page.

Comment: Why would I be asking this question, or have gone to the trouble of cutting my code down to an absolute minimum if it wasn't occurring?It may well be 'nonsensical' but nevertheless I have two identical pages on different hosts and they are displaying in a different fashion. I can't provide links because the test pages are on a local VM.

Comment: @Thilo, good point. I have updated the question to explain why it is not likely to be a cache issue.

Comment: Only a different version of IE can cause that problem that you're having! Keep in mind that the host doesn't change the way the clients browser reads the page...

Comment: Any differences between the servers regarding web server used? URL Rewriting? Stuff like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that a server module is messing with your output and confusing IE. For example, [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) does this for optimization purposes, although I haven't heard of a problem with IE. I would run `diff` on the source code that IE is reading (not the saved file themselves).

If they turn out to be identical, I would suspect an issue with Quirks Mode (which the other answers address more thoroughly than I could).

Answer (score 4):

Let's call your two hosts A and B:

Host A - Everything works fine.

Host B - It's screwed, and `position: fixed` does not work.

The problem is almost certainly that IE is displaying Host B in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

You can verify this by hitting F12, and looking at the Document Mode.

- If it says "IE8 Standards", then things work.
- If it says "Quirks Mode", then things (such as `position: fixed`) won't work.

Here's a guide to determine *exactly* why Internet Explorer is reverting to Quirks Mode:

- http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes

If that seems a little too complicated, you can (in almost all cases) force the correct Document Mode by adding this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

If it helps, some other answers I've written about the same thing:

- [IE not rendering CSS properly when the site is located at networkdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-css-problem-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive/4967594#4967594)
- [IE - differences in behaviour between system deployed locally and remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567021/ie-differences-in-behaviour-between-system-deployed-locally-and-remotely/5567698#5567698)
- [Is it possible IE8 will render CSS differently in Windows 7 vs Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471893/is-it-possible-ie8-will-render-css-differently-in-windows-7-vs-windows-xp/5474275#5474275)

Comment: It was something to do with quirks mode, triggered by a module that was being used by one vhost and not the other. Thanks for the comprehensive answer and links.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which module was it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that one host triggers compatibility mode or quirks mode. I'd check some points:

- Make sure the markup is exactly the same - even a comment at the top of the page may change the rendering.
- Both hosts are defined similarly - for example, both are on trusted intranet locations.
- This is a silly question - but does that happen on all machines? Compatibility mode can be triggered *manually*, and is saved by the browser (per domain, iirc, so it may have been triggered for an inner page on that host and not on another host).
- On the internet, one host may be on the [Compatibility View List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567845%28VS.85%29.aspx). You may be that lucky.
- IIS -

  - Make sure all updated are installed.
  - It is possible to [configure IIS to trigger compatibility mode by sending custom headers](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx):  tricky.

Comment: This started as a comment really, as it is mostly guessing, but grew quite a bit...

Comment: You've definitely got the right idea with `"It is possible, that one host triggers compatibility mode or quirks mode."`

Answer (score 0):

could you try putting !important next to the fixed position before the terminator?

```
.alrtfrnt   { position:fixed !important;top:33%;left:33%;height:150px;width:300px;z-index:9;}
```